# Can we compile CoreML on Server?

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition

I am working with CoreML and ARKit for Face recognition. But i don't want to build CoreML model with app. I have make a coreML model with python Turicate. I want this model to be put on server and it give us a API then i will sent face pictures to this model through this API and then server get back a response in form of JSON.I want this because CoreML size is very high and if we want to more train this model then this user has to download this high size model and compile on device.I have research and found that apple adds a feature to compile CoreML model on device but every time for small training upgradation in model user has to download this high size model again.